# MongoDB getting disconnected automatically, not able to fetch records using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am the newbie to NodeJS and MongoDB. I want to take user input from HTML and pass to the MongoDB as a query. I have indexed MongoDB as per the requirement. I am stuck up with this code. Whenever I run server.js, I am getting an error and MongoDB will get disconnected automatically. Please help me.

```
//user_query.js

var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB";
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

var varName, search;

var name = app.post('/product_search', function(req, res, callback) {
    res.send('Searching for "' + req.body.query + '".');
    search = req.body.query;
    callback(search);
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});

module.exports = { varName: search };


//search.js
var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB";
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var user_query = require('./user_query');

//console.log("Hello: "+user_query.varName);

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    db.collection("cellPhones").find({$text:{$search: user_query.varName}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;     
        console.log(result);     
    });  
    db.close(); 
});`enter code here`
```

Comment: please post the content of `user_query` file

Comment: Remove the `db.close()` or at least place it "within" the callback of `.toArray()` The problem is the call to "close" gets made "before" the actual query is executed or finished. So putting it in the callback makes sure the result is returned before the connection is closed. `console.log(result); db.close() // put me in here ; } // remove the db.close() here`

Comment: @BertrandMartel Thanks for replying. The first code snippet is of user_query.js...

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for replying. I am trying your solution. Any suggestion regarding which file should I compile first?

Comment: It's JavaScript. You don't "compile" anything. Ideally your application "should" only every make **one** connection to the database and never hang it up over the entire life cycle. That's how the rest of us do it. I'm pointing out your *"error"* being that you are closing the connection before it actually does anything. Understand now?

Comment: @NeilLunn oh, okay. I removed db.close(). Still I am not able to get the data. Is my method correct, to query MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `callback(search)`, which is basically `next(search)` you end up with your handler in router and pass some data to middlewares.

According to the nodejs convention, the first argument in callbacks is - error. So, what you do - is kind of throwing error.
This is the first problem. So you should resolve it this way:

```
next(null, search);
```

Then, as far as you've picked such approach (with middlewares) - you have to add serving this query middleware somewhere, that will query database and respond to the browser. Very scratch (after you route add):

```
app.use(function(err, req, res) {
  // query db
  // send result to the res.send();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly. I am bit confused; I did following: app.use(function(err, req, res) {
  // query db
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  
  db.collection("cellPhones").find({$text:{$search: 
                user_query.varName}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;  
   console.log(result);
   db.close();  
  });  
  //db.close(); 
 });
  // send result to the res.send();
}); which file should I compile first? user_query.js or search.js

Comment: Create mongo connection on server init. Then just use it. What do you mean by compile?